# Should response of rest api contain ID of a resource?

Tags: rest, api, api-design

What is a good practice or a standard in rest api, should a server response contain ID of a resource?

For example this response contains id of a resource

```
GET /users/5
{
"user_id": 5
"first_name" : "John",
"last_name" : "Doe",
"minutes_active": 10
}
```

And this assumes that an id of a resource is one stated in the url of a request

```
GET /users/5
{
"first_name" : "John",
"last_name" : "Doe",
"minutes_active": 10
}
```

Comment: If your client needs that ID to do something with it (for example to include it in a command) then do include it otherwise don't. If you want a RESTFUL api then your client receive the links from the server and it does not construct them by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> this assumes that an id of a resource is one stated in the url of a request

From the perspective of the client, URI are opaque; if you are communicating information to the client by putting it into a URI that they are expected to parse, then you have lost the plot.

If your API needs to make the id available to the client, then the id should be included in the representation of the resource.

> What do you mean by "URI are opaque; if you are communicating information to the client by putting it into a URI that they are expected to parse..."? It looks to me like the client created the URI, so ostensibly it already knows the ID...?

Typically, a REST API client *follows links*, rather than constructing the URI.  There's nothing in the HTTP request that tells you how the client came to choose that particular URI -- it might be a bookmark, or a link in some other representation, or the result of filling in a form.

Comment: What do you mean by "URI are opaque; if you are communicating information to the client by putting it into a URI that they are expected to parse..."? It looks to me like the client created the URI, so ostensibly it already knows the ID...?